# How to fix failures like CloneUserRepository and DestroyContainer in Airflow?

Tags: github, airflow, scheduler

Its my first week of using Airflow. I am trying to schedule snowflake sql codes which are sitting in github. Code is basically refreshing the table with new records (runs locally in snowflake just fine). But the Airflow DAG is failing for these 2 tasks: CloseUserRepository and DestroyContainer. I have checked the airflow documentation [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html)  but couldn't find anything specifically on it.

Below is the graphview of the DAG I am trying to run. When I look into the log details for failed CloneUserRepository task, it looks like DAG is not able to access github repository as I have kept it as private. My understanding was: if I am using organizational github and airflow, my creds should act as a bridge and let airflow access the github comfortably. But I am not an expert and hence looking for a help here. I certainly don't want to make it public even for testing my hypothesis.

Any expert comment/suggestion much appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just checked with an airflow SME in my company. That was indeed the problem. And it worked fine after making the repository public (within the enterprise).